# How to use Example from Adobe reference in FlashDevelop IDE

Tags: apache-flex, flashdevelop

I try to use the example from Adobe help reference as following address:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/Tree.html#includeExamplesSummary

I open FlashDevelop IDE, creat a new Flex 3 project, then copy the code of example to the main.mxml, save it, then run builder.

It failed with "...\TreeExample\TreeExample\src\Main.mxml(5): Error: Could not resolve <s:Application> to a component implementation." error message.

There is a "How to use this example" link beside this example, but I didn't find any useful information I want.

How can I run this example in FlashDevelop IDE?

Comment: s:Application is a Flex 4 component so a Flex 3 project isn't appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, that you try to compile component from newer Flex sdk with older one (3.x instead of 4.x)

Download newest from Adobe site:
http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Flex+SDK

And install it to Flash Develop:
http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=AS3